# Could I upload a file through a web service?

Tags: web-services, webservice-client

I want my customers to upload some file to my server. My current design is as below:

- I make a folder on my server with R/W permission to Anonymous user like this: http://myserver/uploads
- Customer contact my web service to indicate they want to upload something, and the webservice returned a path like this:  http://myserver/uploads/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx, the xxx part is a GUID.

But I don't know what to do next? I believe customer has the permission to write to the virtual path returned by the web service, but how could I write my client-side code so that it can actually copy things to that virtual path? My client-side is a Win32 application, not a web page.

What if I want the customer upload files within a web page, how to do that? I know that there's a "PUT" method in HTTP protocol that could be used to upload things to server, but how to use that?

I am new to this kind of web development. I hope I made myself clear. If there's any better design, please let me know.

Many many thanks.

### Update - 1 - 0:59 2010/12/27

A similar question: [How to upload a file to a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-wcf-service)

Some possible solutions:

[Image Upload Web Service in C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ImageUploadWS.aspx)

[Upload any type of File through a C# Web Service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/uploadwithcsharpws05032007121259pm/uploadwithcsharpws.aspx)

[Progress Indication while Uploading/Downloading Files using WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_FileTransfer_Progress.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid allowing anyone to write files to a directory.  I know you have set up permissions to help guard against anything bad happening, but it is still setup to where anyone can read/write to it, not just to person you've told the URL to.  Security through obscurity is not a best practice.

What kind of webservice are you using?  WCF, SOAP, something else all together?  I would have the file upload still be a service call (not just some PUT command to a directory).  That way you can still apply security if needed.  When you get right down to it, a file is nothing more than an array of bytes, so you can have your web service accept an array of bytes and write it out to the correct location.  If I had a better idea of what technologies you are using (php, asp.net, jsp, etc)  Then I might be able to make more precise recommendations.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using WCF, asp.net and javascript.

Comment: If using WCF, then you can stream a file up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx.  I've done this once before and it worked well. The only trouble I ran into is when a file took more than 5 minutes to fully upload, then I ran in to an issue with the default clock skew of 5 minutes.  There's ways around it, but it isn't pretty (all the ugliness is in the config files, not in the code).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SOAP attachments](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments), or if not using SOAP, something similar - specifying filename, content type and binary data, Base64-encoded.