# upload file wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, upload

I'll create an WCF for uploading file such as images or pdf files to te server.
How can I create a service that can handle this function ? 
I tried to googling about it, but most of article told me to use Stream as service parameter. But what I want is using byte[] (array) for the file content. because, this service is not only accessing using .nte framework, but also using other technologies, such as php, java, objective-c, etc.

any helps ?

Comment: A byte array is not a file.  Should edit the subject of this question to reflect desire to post a byte array.  Its misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems streaming is your only option. See this [[MSDN example]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx)

See this question : 
[How to upload a file to a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-wcf-service)

You could check out this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx

It talks about just setup WCF Service for receiving arbitrary data, and you can POST from any client (php,java etc)

Answer (score 4):

Create a WCF service method accepting `byte[]` as a parameter:

```
[OperationContract]
public void ReceiveByteArray(byte[] byteArray) { ... }
```

Comment: this wont works with large files. Using [Streaming message transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms731913.aspx) is better. Using byte array as requested is probably a bad idea. Maybe using an http put handler aside the WCF service can be a good idea

Comment: yozora wants to use it across various platforms, the solution is not ideal, but can help in 90% of cases, for rest a smart uploader might be required...

Answer (score 0):

Create a WCF Service method accepting File Stream.

1. using a fileupload control you can perform the task
2. create a Temp folder on client site.

here code...

```
string fileextension = null, FileName = null;

try
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {

        ITransferFile clientUpload = new TransferFileClient();
        RemoteFileInfo uploadRequestInfo = new RemoteFileInfo();
        fileextension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/TempFolder/", FileName + fileextension)));
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/TempFolder/") + FileName + fileextension);

        using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            uploadRequestInfo.FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            uploadRequestInfo.Length = fileInfo.Length;
            uploadRequestInfo.FileByteStream = stream;
            clientUpload.UploadFile(uploadRequestInfo);
        }

    }


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/TempFolder/") + FileName + fileextension))
    {
        File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/TempFolder/") + FileName + fileextension);
    }
}
```