# what to do?uploading of files in WCF C#

Tags: wcf, web-services, file-upload, upload

i've heard that WCF can upload files from one computer to another, my question is,

if i want to do this,

how can i tell computer1 the address of computer2?

thanks

Comment: You need to do some reading about how WCF works. This question is too basic for this environment.

Comment: See this answer, it contains all details for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804469/upload-file-wcf